# Rails3 finding date objects in calendar month

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Most Date methods will do a calculation based on the present time or date and jump to that date in X number of months.  However if one wants to extract all the objects that have a date within a solar month, this works

```
Product.where(['date >= ? AND date <= ?', @products, Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month, Date.today.at_end_of_month.next_month]).all
```

server log shows:

```
date >= '2013-12-01' AND date <= '2013-12-30'
```

But the following fails

```
Product.where(['date >= ? AND date <= ?', @products, Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.month+1, Date.today.at_end_of_month.month+2]).all
```

server log shows:

```
date >= 12 AND date <= 13
```

I also assume there is better shorthand where one could state

```
date IN (?)
```

no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.today.month` returns an integer, not a date. You can do something like `(Date.today + 2.months).at_beginning_of_month`, or `2.months.from_now.at_beginning_of_month`

And yes, you could pass in a range to do a BETWEEN select:

```
Product.where(:date => Date.today.at_beginning_of_month..Date.today.at_end_of_month)
# => "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\"  WHERE (\"products\".\"date\" BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30')"
```

Comment: (Date.today + 2.months).at_beginning_of_month RETURNS undefined method `at_beginning_of_month' for 5184000:Fixnum.  2.months.from_now.at_beginning_of_month  RETURNS date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AND date <= '2014-01-31 23:59:59.999999'

Comment: `2.months` returns a fixnum as it represents a certain number of seconds, but `(Date.today + 2.months)` should return a Time object. What happens when you try just that in your console? What version of Ruby are you using? Note that `at_beginning_of_month` is added from Active Support, not Ruby stdlib, so it only works in Rails console, and not in IRB.

Comment: OK. That's what I'd expect. Are you still having problems, or is this working for you now? Make sure you run the command exactly as I originally wrote it, with the parenthesis. That way the `at_beginning_of_month` is applied to the result of the first operation.

Comment: Yes, both work.  The parenthesis were what hung me up in the first suggesion (note to future readers!).